# Should I cache data or use local storage in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using an external country API to get all country details. Since country information is not going to change very frequently, I want the API to be called only once in a day by each user.

If the user is opening the app before 24 hours after first call, API should not be called but if the user is opening the app after 24 hours, the API should be called again.

I can think of 2 possible ways.

1. Use a storage library like [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) . If I use this, how to clear local storage after 24 hour?
2. Use a caching library.

What is your preferred solution in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you would just need to store one object -

`{"time_stamp": new Date()}`

This object would help keep track of the time and date the api was called.

You would just need to write a function to decide whether to call the external country API or not.

It would be easier if you just used a storage library in this case, however if you would like to store more information then it would be recommended to use cache or a db.